# Where did OSX's x86-64 assembly libc routines go?

Tags: c, macos, libc

First, some useful links to OSX's Libc code:

- Git: https://github.com/aosm/Libc.git (with tags for the different iterations of OSX)
- HTML: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/

There, one can see that Libc 825.40.1 (OSX 10.8.5) still has public asm implementations of functions like memcpy. Notably in `x86_64/string/bcopy_sse42.s`. However, since version 997.1.1 (OSX 10.9), most of them seem to be gone. A few are left in `x86_64/string` though. As can be seen here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/x86_64/string/.

Has the source been closed on the others? Looking at the diff between OSX 10.8 and 10.9 doesn't indicate a place where they may have moved inside of the source tree.

When debugging binaries running on OSX 10.9, it's hard to miss the references to `_platform_memmove`. Indeed, if we look at the source of [bcopy.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/string/bcopy.c), we see:

```
#include <platform/string.h>

void bcopy(const void *src, void *dst, size_t n) {
    _platform_memmove(dst, src, n);
}
```

So perhaps that could yield something useful. Yet for some reason I can't find `(_)platform_memmove`, either through lack of grepping prowess, or macro trickery. Can someone help me find it?

**EDIT**: I tried looking for [platform/string.h](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2014/Aug/msg00001.html), but just like that mailing list poster, I couldn't locate it within the source tree.

**EDIT**: Compiling a source file calling `memcpy` with Xcode's clang (near to 3.4) on OSX 10.9.4 and running it under Instruments shows that `_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem` is being called. Which leads me to believe that the specialized asm variants still exist somewhere.

**EDIT**: dumping libsystem.dylib doesn't give me the comments, but at least it gives me the assembly, there appear to be routines for:

- [Ivy Bridge](https://gist.github.com/aktau/fb28076fc71e9943f91b#file-osx1094_memmove_ivybridge-s) (delegates to Nehalem)
- [Nehalem](https://gist.github.com/aktau/fb28076fc71e9943f91b#file-osx1094_memmove_nehalem-s) (chosen on my system, a 2011 Core i7)
- Merom
- [SSE4.2](https://gist.github.com/aktau/fb28076fc71e9943f91b#file-osx1094_memmove_sse42-s) (presumably similar to the SSE 4.2 version found in older Libc's)
- SSE3
- SSE2
- scalar
- Unknown

Comment: Have you tried looking in `<platform/string.h>`?

Comment: I did try to look for it, but couldn't find it. Someone else already had the same experience: http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2014/Aug/msg00001.html. I will edit the answer.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't.